# Add class to select option in Symfony FormBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

In my Symfony 2 application I am using the `FormBuilder` to create a form for selecting data contained in a generated document.

```
$typeChoices = [
    '001' => 'first factor',
    '002' => 'another factor',
    '003' => 'some surcharge',
    '004' => 'custom discount',
    '005' => 'another surcharge'
];

$formDownload = $this->createFormBuilder(array())
    ->add('category', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'MyApp\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category',
        'choice_label' => 'name'
    ))
    ->add('type', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => $typeChoices,
        'multiple' => true
    ))
    ->add('download', 'submit', array(
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'btn-primary'
        ),
    ))
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('myapp_data_download'))
    ->getForm();
```

The `$typeChoices` data is loaded from an `EntityRepository` - I just simplified the code for this demo.

That way, a select box is generated like that:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" required="required" name="form[type][]" id="form_type">
    <option value="001">first factor</option>
    <option value="002">another factor</option>
    <option value="003">some surcharge</option>
    <option value="004">custom discount</option>
    <option value="005">another surcharge</option>
</select>
```

How can I add a `class` attribute to each `option`? It must be created based on an attribute of the original data coming from the `EntityRepository`. Until now, I was not able to add a `class` attribute to the `option`s when using the `FormBuilder` and I would like to avoid creating the form markup manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New in Symfony 2.7: [Choice form type refactorization](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization)

> In Symfony 2.7 this form type has been completely refactored to
>   support dynamic generation for labels, values, indexes and attributes.
>   This is now possible thanks to the new options choice_label,
>   **choice_name**, **choice_value**, **choice_attr**, **group_by** and
>   **choices_as_values**.

You can for example **generate dynamic choice label**.

**Example:**

```
$builder->add('attending', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        'yes' => true,
        'no' => false,
        'maybe' => null,
    ),
    'choices_as_values' => true,
    'choice_label' => function ($allChoices, $currentChoiceKey) {
        return 'form.choice.'.$currentChoiceKey;
    },
));
```

In your case, you want **manipulate the attribute class** of each option.

**Example:**

```
$builder->add('attending', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        'Yes' => true,
        'No' => false,
        'Maybe' => null,
    ),
    'choices_as_values' => true,
    'choice_attr' => function ($allChoices, $currentChoiceKey) {
        if (null === $currentChoiceKey) {
            return array('class' => 'text-muted');
        }
    },
));
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Add Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType::finishView in Form class

```
/**
 * @param FormView $view
 * @param FormInterface $form
 * @param array $options
 */
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    parent::finishView($view, $form, $options);

    $additionalAttributes = array();

    // myMethod - object method $choice, returns a value that must be replaced by attribute
    foreach ($view->children['type']->vars['choices'] as $id => $choice) {
        $additionalAttributes[$id] = array(
            'class' => $this->propertyAccessor->getValue($choice->data, 'myMethod'),
        );
    }

    foreach ($view->children['type']->children as $id => $child) {
        $child->vars['attr'] = array_replace(
            isset($child->vars['attr']) ? $child->vars['attr'] : array(),
            $additionalAttributes[$id]
        );
    }
}
```

[Symfony2 Form - adding an attribute to the tag option in the select type](http://zeka.kiev.ua/symfony2-form-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3-option-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%82/)